# Consume RSS and JSON

Tags: sxa, rss

Does SXA support consuming an RSS feed or JSON, style it and the render it on the website. I see components to generate RSS but not to consume it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible just ootb, but can be done pretty easily with a bit of custom code and rendering variants.

You can use external data in the variants if it is available in your model. You can read about this on my blog: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/03/external-model-data-SXA-variant-Sitecore.html

What you should do is create a [custom component that can handle rendering variants](https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2017/03/variants-sxa-sitecore-rendering.html). In that component you can add properties (can be as many as you want, can also include complex types if needed). Those properties will be available in your rendering variants - you can add those with the "**Model**" variant.

If you can write the custom component that reads the rss or json data and puts that data in properties, you can use variants to display all that data - making it very flexible to determine what data you want to show (and how).